# missing requirement osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.10.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf

It's my first project that I'm trying to use Karaf and OSGI container.

Latest version of osgi.framework is 1.10.0 and it must fit.
There is osgi.framework package in libraries and manifest.mf has line

```
"Export-Package: org.osgi.dto;version="1.1.1",org.osgi.framework;versio
 n="1.10""
```

I have an error when I start bundle:

```
bundle:start 55
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
        Error starting bundle 55: Unable to resolve SuccessFactorsIntegration [55](R 55.0): missing requirement [SuccessFactorsIntegration [55](R 55.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.10.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[SuccessFactorsIntegration [55](R 55.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.10.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
```

pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>by.MVasilevskiy</groupId>
<artifactId>SuccessFactorsIntegration</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SuccessFactorsIntegration</name>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
      <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        ${project.artifactId}
                    </Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>
                        ${project.name}
                    </Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Version>
                        ${project.version}
                    </Bundle-Version>
                    <Bundle-Activator>
                        ${project.groupId}.Activator
                    </Bundle-Activator>
                    <Private-Package>
                        ${project.groupId}
                    </Private-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

MANIFEST.MF in user.m2\repository\by\MVasilevskiy\SuccessFactorsIntegration\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: by.MVasilevskiy;uses:="org.apache.camel.builder,org.osgi.fra
 mework";version="0.0.1.SNAPSHOT",by.MVasilevskiy.processor;uses:="org.apach
 e.camel";version="0.0.1.SNAPSHOT"
Import-Package: by.MVasilevskiy,by.MVasilevskiy.processor,javax.xml.namespace,ja
 vax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.xpath,org.apache.camel;version="[3.4,4)",org.
 apache.camel.builder;version="[3.4,4)",org.apache.camel.impl;version="[
 3.4,4)",org.apache.camel.model;version="[3.4,4)",org.osgi.framework;ver
 sion="[1.10,2)",org.w3c.dom
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
Tool: Bnd-5.1.1.202006162103
```

Part `org.osgi.framework.system.packages` from `config.properties`

```
# Framework config properties.
#
org.osgi.framework.system.packages= \
 org.osgi.dto;version="1.1",\
 org.osgi.resource;version="1.0",\
 org.osgi.resource.dto;version="1.0";uses:="org.osgi.dto",\
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.9",\
 org.osgi.framework.dto;version="1.9";uses:="org.osgi.dto",\
 org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle;version="1.1";uses:="org.osgi.framework",\
 org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver;version="1.0";uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring",\
 org.osgi.framework.hooks.service;version="1.1";uses:="org.osgi.framework",\
 org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving;version="1.1";uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring",\
 org.osgi.framework.launch;version="1.2";uses:="org.osgi.framework",\
 org.osgi.framework.namespace;version="1.1";uses:="org.osgi.resource",\
 org.osgi.framework.startlevel;version="1.0";uses:="org.osgi.framework",\
 org.osgi.framework.startlevel.dto;version="1.0";uses:="org.osgi.dto",\
 org.osgi.framework.wiring;version="1.2";uses:="org.osgi.framework,org.osgi.resource",\
 org.osgi.framework.wiring.dto;version="1.3";uses:="org.osgi.dto,org.osgi.resource.dto",\
 org.osgi.service.condpermadmin;version="1.1.1";uses:="org.osgi.framework,org.osgi.service.permissionadmin",\
 org.osgi.service.packageadmin;version="1.2";uses:="org.osgi.framework",org.osgi.service.permissionadmin;version="1.2",\
 org.osgi.service.resolver;version="1.1";uses:="org.osgi.resource",\
 org.osgi.service.startlevel;version="1.1";uses:="org.osgi.framework",\
 org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0",\
 org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.5.2";uses:="org.osgi.framework",\
 org.apache.karaf.version;version="4.3.2",\
 org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal;uses:=javax.security.auth;version="4.3.2",\
 org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot;uses:="javax.security.auth,javax.security.auth.callback,javax.security.auth.login,javax.security.auth.spi,org.osgi.framework";version="4.3.2",\
 org.apache.karaf.info;version="4.3.2",\
 ${jre-${java.specification.version}}
```

Comment: Can you check `org.osgi.framework.system.packages` property in Karaf configuration file (`etc/config.properties`)? It contains packages provided by core system bundle.
Also check which version of this package is porvided to the container: `inspect cap osgi.wiring.package` and look for `osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.framework ... required by: ...`

Comment: I added `config.properties`. There is line `org.osgi.framework;version="1.9"` in this file, so   can you give me advice how to update `osgi.framework` to version 1.10.0? I didn't find a detailed description of all the commands.

Comment: Newest Karaf release (v4.3.2) uses OSGi Core R7 (version `7.0.0`), so I think you should use `<version>7.0.0</version>` as a dependency or (I guess) wait for Karaf 5.